# Making PDE dimensionless, IC/BC question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Original PDE;

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = \kappa \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \big( r^2 \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \big), \quad 0 \leq r \leq R, \quad t \geq 0  $$
IC: $ \quad T(r,0)=T_0, \quad $ BC: $\quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}(0,t)=0, \quad k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}(R,t)=-\beta \big( T(R,t)-T_1 \big)$

When scaling to dimensionless form, I use these variables;

$$ x = \frac{r}{R}, \quad u=\frac{T(r,t)-T_1}{T_0-T_1}, \quad \tau=\frac{t}{\alpha} $$

When I put in these three variables into the original PDE, I find that $\alpha = \frac{\kappa}{R^2}$ if I want the PDE to become dimensionless. It now takes the form $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}=\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big( x^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \big)$.

My question is regarding the boundary/initial conditions. When I derive the new dimensionless PDE, every instance of $T$ is replaced with $T_1 + (T_0 - T_1)u$, every instance of $t$ is replaced with $\tau \alpha$, and every instance of $r$ is replaced with $Rx$.

However, when I want to derive the new initial condition, I write $T(r,0)=T_0 \implies T_1 + (T_0 - T_1)u(x,0)=T_0 \implies u(x,0)=1$. My question is, why should I write $u(x,0)$ and not $u(Rx,0)$, since $r=Rx$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ on the left hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the change of variables 
$$u(x,\tau) := \frac{T(R x ,\alpha \tau) - T_1}{T_0 - T_1}$$
This means that
$$u(x,0) = \frac{T(R x, 0) - T_1}{T_0 - T_1} = 1$$
since $T(r,0) = T_0$ for any $r$ in particular $r = Rx$. And
$$\partial_r = R\partial_x, \quad \partial_t  =\alpha \partial_\tau$$
so for example $\partial_t T(r,t) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\partial_\tau T(Rx,\alpha \tau) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\partial_\tau u$. All together we have
$$\frac{1}{\alpha} \partial_\tau u = \frac{\kappa R^2}{x^2}\frac{1}{R}\partial_x ((\frac{x}{R})^2 \frac{1}{R}\partial_x u)$$
$$\partial_\tau u = \frac{\alpha \kappa}{ R^2}\frac{1}{x^2}\partial_x (x^2 \partial_x u)$$
so $\alpha = R^2/\kappa $. This makes sense as $\kappa$ should have units of distance squared over time.

Comment: Hmm I think I understand now, since you pointed out that $T(r,0)=T_0$ for any $r$, so it should also be true for $r=Rx$. This makes sense. I will try this during the weekend for the boundary conditions aswell and see if I can understand it. Thank you for the help!